# How deep does water have to be so a mosquito can lay viable eggs in it?

Tags: physiology

I read about this [idea for a mosquito trap](http://www.instructables.com/id/Mosquito-trap-mosquito-abortion-clinic-or-source-t/) (with a rather tactless name) where the idea seems to be that because the water available for the mosquito eggs is so shallow, they will die somehow or not be viable. Mosquitos are pretty small though, wouldn't they not need much water for the eggs to hatch?

Comment: very little.. even a cup of water is fine for them.. I have seen larvae in the rain water accumulated in old tires as well.  I don't know the exact measure though..

Comment: Very litle. The small puddles which are left after big rainfalls or floodings are usually enough.

Comment: The main constraint is shallow water will evaporate more quickly. The depth that the larve themselves need is very little.

Comment: From own observation: about 1-2 cm is enough to live and hatch.

Comment: They can survive fine in 1cm of water, they just stay at the surface and feed from microrganisms, and a mosqito would probably lay viable eggs in 1cm stagnant water if you forced it to in an aquarium, it may even lay in 0.7mm of water, it depends on the species. Mosquitos probably have some way of judging if a water source is stable and if it is likely to evaporate. The larger the body of water, the less it is vulnerable to sudden changes in pH and Temps, aglification, cloudings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many mosquitoes, such as Culex quinquefasciatus, lay their eggs on the surface of fresh or stagnant water. The water may be in tin cans, barrels, horse troughs, ornamental ponds, swimming pools, puddles, creeks, ditches, catch basins or marshy areas. Mosquitoes prefer water sheltered from the wind by grass and weeds ([reference](http://www.mosquito.org/biology)). There are mosquitoes like Aedes taeniorhyncus (floodwater mosquitoes) which can even lay eggs in moist soil (because the eggs need to dry out before they can hatch) which then waits for the rainy season for hatching. These eggs are capable of surviving through summer, winter and spring to find the right time to hatch ([reference](http://mosquito.ifas.ufl.edu/Mosquito_Habitats.htm)). Water is necessary during the life cycle of a mosquito but how much is never an issue. Even the top of some mushrooms can be a place for mosquitoes to lay eggs ([reference](http://www.clarku.edu/~tlivdahl/back/index.html)).

Answer (score 0):

I have them in my property breeding in my containers all the time. From a few inches gets the best results (more mosquitoes) but I’ve gotten colonies in water up to 2-3’ deep.